# How to push Blazor page onto stack so it doesn't need to be refreshed on nav back

Tags: .net-core, blazor-server-side

Complete nooby to web development (used C# and F# for desktop apps in the past).

I was playin around with Blazor server side (no more Javascript - yea!) and wanted to know, is there a way to save a page's DOM using Blazor, so that when you follow a link and navigate back, the DOM does not have to be reconstructed for the original page?

Currently using OnInitializedAsync in .razor page to construct original page - it gets called again when the nav back is taken.

Does this even make sense to do? It seems to me that in many web sites using different techonology, a nav back does not re-construct the page, the DOM is saved somewhere and the browser merely 're-paints' using previously constructed tree. Or is this also a complete misunderstanding?